# How common object/subject case being applied to determiners/demonstrative/articles instead of nouns?

Tags: cases, determiners

I'm talking about a language where say, a certain case is *only* expressed on the determiners/demonstrative/article?

So they might say for example:

> Which-a Cat?
> Which-`LOC.` Cat?

Rather than:

> Which Cat-a?
> Which Cat-`LOC.`?

(Where `LOC` is the locative for this Examplish sentence).

How (in)common is this?

Comment: It’s not very common to mark tense or aspect on nouns _or_ determiners. They’re usually marked on verbs.

Comment: And to answer the corresponding question, it's very common to mark tense, mood, and aspect on auxiliary verbs and particles.

Comment: @janus maybe I'm thinking of case?

Comment: @Pureferret That would make more sense, since case is virtually always marked on nouns, adjectives and/or determiners. (I can’t think of any languages I know of that mark case only on determiners and not on nouns. The reverse is not that uncommon, though.)

Comment: @janus does my change make sense?

Comment: Yes, now the question makes sense, and is actually quite an interesting one. The three groups usually marked for case are not equally likely to be marked: it’s nouns > determiners > adjectives, and I can’t think of a single language I know of that doesn’t follow this ordering.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Standard German is the first one that comes to mind; most of the case marking on nouns has been eroded away (so that only the genitive is commonly distinguished), but the marking on determiners and adjectives is still alive and thriving.

Comment: @Draconis German does still mark it in all three, though; there’s just a higher rate of syncretism in nouns than in (strong) adjectives. (In the plural, of course, it’s the dative that’s most commonly distinguished.) There are also individual cases where a noun or adjective is indeclinable but it’s determiners aren’t, which would match what this question is about (e.g., Hebrew names in Biblical Greek), but those are just individual cases within a system that itself works differently.

Comment: In Tamil, 

வந்தான் வடிவேலன் (Vadivelan came).
வந்தானா வடிவேலன்? (Did Vadivelan come?).

அது கருப்பு பூனை (That is a black cat).
அதுவா கருப்பு? (Is it/that black?)

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_case#Tamil

Comment: @janus Wolof seems to use temporal pronouns instead of conjugating verbs